# Old Query methods success() purge()

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, query-performance

In the Project was used old version of mysql++, recently it was updated.
After compilation I got some error messages:
«class mysqlpp::Query» has no member named «success»
«class mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult» has no member named «purge»
Does anyone know what should be used instead this ?

Comment: What version of mysql++ were you using before, and what are you using now? Have you taken a look at the changelogs between the two versions?

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

> Removed several “smelly” methods:
>
> purge(): was an internal implementation detail, not something for end user code to call
>
> Removed success() in Connection, Query

from
[Incompatible Library Changes](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql%2B%2B/doc/html/userman/breakages.html#abi-1.7.18)

But I have not idea how to replace it.

Comment: Please, add it to your question instead of add an answer.

Comment: Looks like you've managed to lose access to the account you used for posting your question. It was unregistered and you could only use it on the same device where you submitted the question (and only without removing cookies). Your new one, under which you've posted this "answer", is unregistered too. Consider registering your account and then requesting that it [be merged](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) with the other one. That'll restore your control over your question and let you freely edit it, comment on it and accept an answer (once you receive one worth accepting).